# Jekyll: command not found problem despite installated with most recent versions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, homebrew

I am having trouble with the Jekyll installation. Everything is up to date with Ruby, Homebrew and Gems:

```
Quocs-MacBook-Air:~ quochoantrinh$ brew -v
Homebrew 2.1.6
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 2796; last commit 2019-07-01)
Quocs-MacBook-Air:~ quochoantrinh$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin16]
Quocs-MacBook-Air:~ quochoantrinh$ gem -v
3.0.3
```

Then I ran the following from the Jekyll on macOS setup from the official website (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
```

Afterwards I did the next commands:

```
gem install --user-install bundler jekyll
export PATH=$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.3/bin:$PATH
```

However when I run jekyll in my terminal it gives me the "command not found".

This is my gem env

```
Quocs-MacBook-Air:~ quochoantrinh$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/quochoantrinh/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/quochoantrinh/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.yarn/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/anaconda3/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/anaconda3/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/anaconda/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.gem/ruby/2.6.3/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.yarn/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/anaconda3/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/anaconda3/bin
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/anaconda/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
     - /Users/quochoantrinh/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Have you tried in a new shell window?

Comment: Yes I closed my terminal. Force quitted and then reopened and ran the same commands to no avail. :(

Comment: Okay so I think I located my error. I have multiple shell paths that are causing problems. Do you know how to remove specific shell path in the gem env?

Comment: I wish to change the USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY from /Users/quochoantrinh/.gem/ruby/2.6.0 tp /Users/quochoantrinh/.gem/ruby/2.6.3.

Comment: I don’t know how to do that :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here, but to fix your immediate problem, I believe this should do it:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"
```

When you use the `--user-install` flag, it installs gems in the `USER_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY` that's mentioned when you run `gem env`, which in your case is `/Users/quochoantrinh/.gem/ruby/2.6.0`, and then you have to add `/bin` when you add it to the `PATH`. It's not so much that you want to change the `USER_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY`, but that you need to set the `PATH` to point to the `USER_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY`. I know it's not very intuitive because you would think that you want to use the path that corresponds to your current Ruby version (2.6.3), but the `USER_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY` always ends with a 0. It only uses the first 2 digits of the Ruby version. If you ever upgrade to 2.7.2, which is the latest version as of today, your PATH has to point to `2.7.0`.

Note that running the `export PATH` command above will only work during your current session. If you want to be able to use `jekyll` every time you quit and relaunch Terminal, or open a new tab, you need to add that `export PATH` command to your shell startup file, typically either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`. If you're not sure which shell you are using, read this: https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/which-shell-am-i-using-how-can-i-switch/

I also noticed that you seem to have installed Ruby with both Homebrew and RVM. This could potentially cause problems. I always recommend that people install Ruby with a Ruby manager (such as RVM, rbenv, and chruby), because most of them automatically set everything up for you. You don't have to worry about setting the `PATH` manually and thinking about whether to add `--user-install`. My preferred manager is [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) because it's the lightest and easiest to use.

Based on your `gem env`, it looks like you are currently using the Homebrew version of Ruby, so I wanted to let you know of another issue you might run into. (I can tell it's Homebrew by looking at the `RUBY_EXECUTABLE`, and I know from experience that Homebrew installs things in `/usr/local` and I recognize that path as the Homebrew Ruby.)

Let's say you want to install `rails` months from now, and you type `gem install rails` (without the `--user-install` flag). Once it's installed, if you try to use the `rails` command, you will get "command not found", because when you use the Homebrew version of Ruby, and you don't use `--user-install`, the gem will get installed in a directory managed by Homebrew, not in your `USER_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY`. The Jekyll documentation forgot to point out that you need to add the Homebrew gems location to your `PATH`. The fix is covered in my [definitive guide to installing Ruby gems on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/#homebrew-ruby), and also in the [pull request I opened to fix the Jekyll documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/8496).

To understand more about how `PATH` works, and why you can get a "command not found" error, I recommend this article:
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/troubleshooting-command-not-found-in-the-terminal/