# Issue with `Jekyll Command Not Found` on MacBook Pro with Sonoma 14.2.1 and M1 Pro Chip

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew, jekyll

I am experiencing an issue with Jekyll on my MacBook Pro running Sonoma 14.2.1 with an M1 Pro chip. Initially, I encountered a problem related to the system Ruby, so I installed Ruby 3.3.0 using rbenv 1.2.0.

Afterward, I installed Bundler and Jekyll using Gem 3.5.4 with the following command following the [Jekyll's setup tutorial](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/):

`gem install jekyll bundler`

Bundler was successfully installed (I verified it with `bundler -v` showing version 2.5.5), but I ran into a problem with Jekyll. When I tried to check the Jekyll version using `jekyll -v`, I receive the following error:

`zsh: command not found: jekyll`

However, Jekyll seems to be installed since `gem which jekyll` returns:

`/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll.rb`

When I try to run `gem jekyll` or `gem 'jekyll'` results in an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnknownCommandError)

Unknown command jekyll
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:206:in `find_command'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:251:in `invoke_command'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:193:in `process_args'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:151:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:56:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/gem:12:in `<main>'
```

Then I found a related post ("[Ruby gem jekyll is installed but is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76210664/ruby-gem-jekyll-is-installed-but-is-not-recognized)"), but their solution seems specific to Windows environment, which doesn't work for my case.

Also, after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844252/jekyll-command-not-found-problem-despite-installated-with-most-recent-versions), I wonder if it's related to my `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 patchlevel 0) [arm64-darwin23]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/'username'/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /opt/homebrew/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/'username'/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - arm64-darwin-23
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
     - /Users/'username'/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
     - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
```

But I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone help me resolve this issue so that Jekyll runs correctly on my system?

Comment: The typical way would be to run `bundle install` and then call jekyll as `bundle exec jekyll`, did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Executables installed via bundler should be run with `bundle exec`. For example

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

If you leave the `bundle exec` part out, your shell will look for jekyll e.g., in your `PATH`. I don't know of an easy way to make that route to bundler.